# Change "limit" clause in Geokit's "closest" scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, limit, closest, geokit

it sounds like not difficult at all but after looking for a while I can't find a way to change the `limit` of the `closest` scope in `Geokit-rails`.

I've tried to overide the definition of this method which is defined according to the documentation as:

```
    def closest(options = {})
       geo_scope(options).order("#{distance_column_name} asc").limit(1)
    end
```

but with no success.

Any idea? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's an older version of geokit-rails/geokit, now the definition is:

```
def closest(options = {})
  by_distance(options).first(1)
end
```

So no need to override anything, your code could simply say:

`MyClass.by_distance(options).limit(my_limit)`

Note: Try to avoiding monkey patching existing code. If you did what was suggested in another comment it might work now, but as soon as you update geokit/geokit-rails you risk it breaking as implementations do change (e.g. the closest method is implemented rather differently.

Answer (score 0):

You can override this method, something like:

```
 module Geokit
   def closest(options = {})
     geo_scope(options).order("#{distance_column_name} asc").limit(options[:limit] || 1)
   end
 end
```

and put this file in config/initializers folder and restart server. Note: put correct module name, classes. Consider it like a path to method.